# first day != "first day of this month"

Tags: php, datetime

There's a really strange behaviour in PHP when using "first day" to modify a date.

> `'first day' ' of'?` Sets the day of the first of the current month. (http://php.net/manual/de/datetime.formats.relative.php)

```
$currentMonthDate = new DateTime("2014-07-30 10:26:00.000000");
echo $currentMonthDate->format('Ym');

$currentMonthDate->modify('first day');
echo $currentMonthDate->format('Ym');
```

> 201407 / 201407 *OK*

```
$currentMonthDate = new DateTime("2014-07-31 10:26:00.000000");
echo $currentMonthDate->format('Ym');

$currentMonthDate->modify('first day');
echo $currentMonthDate->format('Ym');
```

> 201407 / **201408** *WHY?*

```
$currentMonthDate = new DateTime("2014-08-01 10:26:00.000000");
echo $currentMonthDate->format('Ym');

$currentMonthDate->modify('first day');
echo $currentMonthDate->format('Ym');
```

> 201408 / 201408 *OK*

I found this behaviour on our production-server running PHP 5.2, so I assumed it's a ancient bug, but it occurs in PHP 5.3 (http://phptester.net/) and 5.5 on our test-server.

If I use "first day of this month" in PHP 5.2 the same behaviour occurs. In PHP 5.5 "first day of this month" works as expected.

Is the "first day"-behaviour a bug? And how to get the "first day of this month" in PHP 5.2 without doing weird conversions between `string` and `date`?

Comment: FWIW, I wouldn't rely too much on `strtotime`/`DateTime` "magic instructions" anyway. To do it manually, you simply do: `$date->setDate($date->format('Y'), $date->format('m'), 1)`

Comment: This was a [known bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=53778)

Comment: 99% sure it's because of time zones.

Comment: @MarkBaker That bug was fixed in 5.3, the question says he gets the error in 5.3.

Comment: @MarkBaker As I mentioned "[...] it occurs in PHP 5.3 (http://phptester.net/) and **5.5** on our test-server."

Comment: I opened a bug report for PHP 5.5.15, since this bug was not properly fixed (https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=67722)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like this issue is a Documentation Problem.

> From Derick in bug #51096:
>       "first day" and "last day" should be "+1 day" and "-1 day".
>
> The documentation should be updated to reflect this behaviour, as
>   currently the "first/last day of" section says the "of" is optional
>   when it is not.

---

### UPDATE

The documentation is now fixed. So the `' of'?` is not optional anymore.

> `'first day of'`  Sets the day of the first of the current month.

Comment: To get those four hours of your life back, just send a self-addressed stamped envelope to .. ah wait, they don't do that anymore. Shucks.